# Android WebView Font Size Wrong

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm working with android webview to open a wordpress site. When I open site in chrome mobile website are load correct, like this:

correct view in chrome

[image]

But, when I open site in my webview, fonte size of website header are load smalltest:

wrong font size

[image]

I tried change font size in android settings but does not work fine...

This is my webview code:

```js
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        mywebViewfull = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webnavinicial);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebViewfull.getSettings();
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
        mywebViewfull.loadUrl(url);
        mywebViewfull.setWebViewClient(new mywebViewfullClient());
```

How can I fix it? Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0):

looks like setTextSize is [depreciated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.TextSize.html), probably not your issue.

Are you using a css library such as bootstrap/semantic-ui? You should check the media queries within that framework, your usage of classes, or your custom css.

The mark-up would be helpful to see.